# Pandas - Scale within a group using a value from the group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My data consist of groups which have received a variety of treatments and then had some result measured, similar to this:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({
'group':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
'treatment':['control', 'high_dose', 'low_dose', 'control', 'high_dose', 'low_dose'],
'result':[2, 6, 4, 3, 12, 15]})

  group  treatment  result
0     A    control       2
1     A  high_dose       6
2     A   low_dose       4
3     B    control       3
4     B  high_dose      12
5     B   low_dose      15
```

I would like to scale the results within each group using the control value within each group to achieve a result like this:

```
  group  treatment  result  result_group_stand
0     A    control       2                    1
1     A  high_dose       6                    3
2     A   low_dose       4                    2
3     B    control       3                    1
4     B  high_dose      12                    4
5     B   low_dose      15                    5
```

Where every result in group "A" has been scaled by the Control value of 2, and every value in group "B" has been scaled by the Control value of 3. All of the examples I have seen use groupby to scale by a summary measurement (sum, max, min, etc...), but I cant find an example that uses a value of a specific treatment within the group. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Use a mapping with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
X['result_group_stand'] = (X['result']
                           .div(X['group']
                                .map(X[X['treatment'].eq('control')]
                                      .set_index('group')['result'])
                               )
                          )
```

Or with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
X['result_group_stand'] = (X['result']
                           .div(X['result'].where(X['treatment'].eq('control'))
                                .groupby(X['group']).transform('first')
                               )
                          )
```

Output:

```
  group  treatment  result  result_group_stand
0     A    control       2                 1.0
1     A  high_dose       6                 3.0
2     A   low_dose       4                 2.0
3     B    control       3                 1.0
4     B  high_dose      12                 4.0
5     B   low_dose      15                 5.0
```